# GRADLE tasks run configuration

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, gradle, build.gradle

I have a project that consists of two parts: Spring Boot and React.
In my Spring Boot `build.gradle` config I specified what actions should be performed in order to build and run the application.

Here is how it looks like:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.5.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
  id "com.github.node-gradle.node" version "2.2.4"
}

group = 'com.vtti'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.10-FINAL'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
        compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.10-FINAL'
        compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.10-FINAL'
        compile 'com.sendgrid:sendgrid-java:4.1.2'
        compile 'org.json:json:20190722'
        compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.11.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

node {
  // Version of node to use.
  version = '10.16.3'
  // Version of Yarn to use.
  yarnVersion = '1.21.1'

  // Base URL for fetching node distributions (change if you have a mirror).
  distBaseUrl = 'https://nodejs.org/dist'

  // If true, it will download node using above parameters.
  // If false, it will try to use globally installed node.
  download = true

  // Set the work directory for unpacking node
  workDir = file("${project.buildDir}/nodejs")
  // Set the work directory for YARN
  yarnWorkDir = file("${project.buildDir}/yarn")
  // Set the work directory where node_modules should be located
  nodeModulesDir = file("${project.projectDir}")
}


task appYarnInstall(type: YarnTask) {
  description = "Install all dependencies from package.json"
  workingDir = file("${project.projectDir}/src/main/client")
  args = ["install"]
}

task appYarnBuild(type: YarnTask) {
  description = "Build production version of the React client"
  workingDir = file("${project.projectDir}/src/main/client")
  args = ["run", "build"]
}

task copyClient(type: Copy) {
  from 'src/main/client/build'
  // into 'build/resources/main/static/.'
  into 'src/main/resources/static/.'
}

appYarnBuild.dependsOn appYarnInstall
copyClient.dependsOn appYarnBuild
compileJava.dependsOn copyClient
```

When I run `gradlew build` everything works properly, Gradle performs `yarn install`, `yarn build`, etc.

However, when I run `gradlew bootRun` and want just to compile and run a project, it performs all the `yarn` actions again and builds a new front-end, which leads in multiple "changed files" that are visible for git and should be committed again.

**Is that possible to specify when tasks should be run and run them only on `gradlew build` and not on `gradlew bootRun`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been asked before, but in your specific case this might be what you're looking for:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
  if (graph.hasTask(bootRun)) {
    tasks.withType(YarnTask){
      enabled = false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Questions like this appear quite often and the answers almost always treat symptoms instead of the actual cause. Most of the solutions will include one of the following Gradle features:

- The command line option `-x` or its programmatical equivalent `gradle.startParameter.excludedTaskNames`
- Direct access to `gradle.taskGraph`
- The `onlyIf` clause of a task

In most cases, these solutions are actually dirty hacks that may or may not backfire later.

The actual problem in a lot of these cases are tasks that are configured and wired in the wrong way. A common misconception in the Gradle world is the idea that there are only a few tasks that may be called from the command line. Based on this assumption, the whole build script is designed around these tasks (often only the task `build` from the Java plugin). In these cases, the whole build script consists of `dependsOn` statements that somehow execute the tasks in the right order when `gradle build` is called. Your question with its focus on the commands (not the tasks) `gradlew build` and `gradlew bootRun` shows the same problem:

> Is that possible to specify when tasks should be run and run them only on `gradlew build` and not on `gradlew bootRun`?

A much better question to your problem would be:

> Is it possible to run the tasks `appYarnInstall` and `appYarnBuild` only when they need to run?

As you explained in your question, the actual problem is caused by the fact that the tasks are run **again**. So, maybe we should figure out when they need to run? If I understand your project structure right, there are two situations where they need to run:

- If the front-end does not exist at all (e.g. on a fresh checkout)
- If some front-end source files changed

Now you could implement this logic in your build script, but Gradle provides this out of the box with its [incremental build support](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-incremental-build-support). You just need to define the inputs and the outputs of tasks that create files and Gradle will figure out when the tasks need to run.

Since I do not fully understand which of your tasks processes what files (and I'm not familiar with the Gradle Node plugin), it is hard for me to give you a fully working build script, but let me instead give you some hints:

- Do not mix source directories processed by Gradle with source directories processed by an external system like Node or Yarn. The `workingDir` hack becomes necessary because those tools expect another repository layout. In your current setup, task results end up inside a source directory (`src/main/client/build`).
- Do not use a task of type `Copy`. Instead, define the outputs of your task `appYarnBuild` and use this task as an additional input of `processResources`. This also eliminates your task dependency on `compileJava`.
- Always store results from your tasks inside `buildDir` and not in subfolders of `src`. This way you may always create a clean build using `gradle clean build`. If tasks create files inside `src`, they won't be deleted during `clean` and may cause problems in later builds.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude a task from being executed using the -x command-line option and providing the name of the task to exclude.

e.g.
gradle bootRun -x appYarnInstall